# What is the proper/best way to have multiple add_filter for wp-job-manager-resume

Tags: filters

What is the best/proper way to implement multiple filters from one function or using my `add_filter` one time? If I can not combine multiple functions or actions in my one filter what is the proper naming I should use to avoid conflicts?

I am modifying the "Add Resume" Page for the wp-job-manager-resume add-on plugin. I am following the tutorial on their website for adding, removing, and (right now) renaming fields. [Editing Resume Form](https://wpjobmanager.com/document/resume-manager-editing-submission-fields/). I am using add_filter and I want to see how I can optimize what I am doing by combining the many filters I want to make into 1 function. I want to see if there is some way to combine multiple filters into one:

```
// Add our own function to filter the fields
add_filter( 'submit_resume_form_fields', 'custom_submit_resume_form_fields' );

// This is the function which takes the fields, modifies them, and returns them
function custom_submit_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['resume_fields']['candidate_title']['label'] = "Job Type";

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'submit_resume_form_fields', 'custom_submit_resume_form_fields' );

function custom_submit_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['resume_fields']['candidate_photo']['label'] = "Profile Image";

    return $fields;
}
```

So I want to end up with something like

```
add_filter( 'submit_resume_form_fields', 'custom_submit_resume_form_fields' );

function custom_submit_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {
   $fields['resume_fields'] array(['candidate_title']['label'] = "Job Type",
   ['candidate_photo']['label'] = "Profile Image");

   return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something in your question, but just move the line from one function to the other...

```
function custom_submit_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['resume_fields']['candidate_title']['label'] = "Job Type";
    $fields['resume_fields']['candidate_photo']['label'] = "Profile Image";

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Ok I actually just found an example of this in some other code. I didn't realize this was a legal way to do it.